# Como deixar o foco na tela ttk.Treeview, congelando as telas anteriores?

Tags: python-3.x, treeview

Fiz uma aplicação em Python 3.6 que chama outro script em python para montar uma tela ttk.Treeview com as informações de banco de dados e esses dados apresentados poderem ser manipulados (alteração e exclusão).

Acontece que não consigo deixar essa tela ttk.Treeview com o foco permanente, já que quando se tecla "alt + tab" o foco passa para a tela anterior que chamou esse script.

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Tentei utilizar "transient" mas não estou obtendo sucesso.

Parte do script que chama o outro script python:

```
def consultacadastro( posi ):
    if str(nrbancoget) != "":
        a = ConsultaCadastroGeral.Inicio()
```

Parte do programa que mostra as informações ttk.Treeview:

## Início do programa

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk, Button, ttk, Frame, Toplevel, Label, Entry, StringVar
from tkinter import messagebox
from Gerenciador import Gerenciador
from PgmFuncoes import PgmFuncoes

class ConsultaCadastroGeral:
    def Inicio():
        root = Tk()
        root.title("Consulta Usuários - Geral")
        CustomTree(root).pack(expand=1, fill="both")

class CustomTree(Frame):
    def **init**(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.**init**(self, master, *args, **kwargs)

```
    # Define tamanhos mínimos e máximos da tela
    master.minsize( width = 500, height= 200)       
    master.maxsize( width = 500, height= 200)

    self.focus_force()

    # Define botão de sair da tela
    self.top = Frame(self)
    self.edit_button = Button(self.top, text="Sair", font = "bold", fg = "blue", command=master.destroy)
    self.edit_button.pack(side="top")
    self.top.pack(fill="x")

    self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self)

    # Define tamanho da coluna
    self.tree.column("#0",minwidth=0,width=0)

    # Cria barra de rolagem      
    barra = Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self.tree.yview)

    # Adiciona barra de rolagem
    self.tree.configure(yscroll=barra.set)
    barra.pack( side = RIGHT, fill=Y )

    self.tree["columns"] = ("one", "two", "tree", "four", "five")
    self.tree.column("one", width=100, anchor="se")
    self.tree.column("two", width=100, anchor="se")
    self.tree.column("tree",width=100, anchor="se")
    self.tree.column("four",width=100, anchor="se")
    self.tree.column("five",width=100, anchor="center")
    self.tree.heading("one", text="Número Banco")
    self.tree.heading("two", text="Número Agência")
    self.tree.heading("tree", text="Conta Corrente")
    self.tree.heading("four", text="Saldo Inicial (R$)")
    self.tree.heading("five", text="Data Inicial")
```

"

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Bem pessoal, como não obtive ajuda dos mais experientes no assunto, resolvi pesquisar muito e acabei achando a solução para o meu problema. Eu retirei a chamada do outro script em python e coloquei a sua lógica em uma classe no script principal, onde está definida a variável da classe Tk:
raiz = Tk() Janela(raiz) raiz.mainloop()
e utilizei "transient" reportando à "raiz".

Parece bem simples a solução agora, então fica a dica: quando for precisar chamar um script de outro script python, o qual mostrará uma tela (Treeview ou não), prefira incluir dentro de uma classe do seu script "chamador" a lógica desse script que seria chamado, evitando essa chamada e podendo manipular os frames com "transient"; Não sei se fui claro, pois tenho muito que andar na linguagem python e em POO, mas enfatizo que é só correr atrás do prejuízo e ter paciência para pesquisar na internet, pois sempre há alguém que acaba te ajudando de alguma forma, mesmo às vezes nem sabendo que o está.

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso você deve inserir os seguintes comandos no root da aplicação/janela ativa

```
master.focus_force()
master.grab_set()
```

- `master` = Variável que está o root ou TopLevel da janela
- `.focus_force()` => Força o foco na janela ao abrir
- `.grab_set()` => Não deixa acessar outra janela aberta do seu programa enquanto essa janela estiver aberta